# Setting up a array of callbacks and trying to use array index as value in callback

Tags: javascript, callback, function-pointers

When I setup an array of callbacks this way I get 20 in the dialog window for all callbacks.  I'd like to get the index in the array instead.  Is this possible?  The function that calls the callback is expecting the callback to have one parameter.  I don't control the caller of the callback because it is part of an external library.  Any help is appreciated.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  callbackDB[i] = function(data) {
    alert(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `i` is evaluated when the function is called, you'll need to scope that value of `i` in a new function execution in order to retain the value you expect.

```
     // returns a function that closes around the `current_i` formal parameter.
var createFunction = function( current_i ) {
    return function( data ) {
        alert( current_i );
    };
};

     // In each iteration, call "createFunction", passing the current value of "i"
     // A function is returned that references the "i" value you passed in.
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  callbackDB[i] = createFunction( i );
}
```

Comment: I had to use the keyword function instead of var for createFunction but otherwise this worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: @Xavier: That was just sloppy of me. I meant to do `var createFunction = function( current_i ) {...`. Doing a declaration as `function createFunction(...` is good too.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using an Object.

```js
var callbackDB = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  callbackDB[i] = {
    value: i,
    callback: function() {
      alert(this.value);
    }
  };
}
   
callbackDB[5].callback();
```

In this case will be necessary to call to the function (In the example it was called "callback")