# Adding parameter to callback function within a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback, event-listener

I tried to get similiar questions to this one, but was unable to find a solution that fits me. I have the following code

```
for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("btn_"+keys[i]).addEventListener('click', function(){changeTab(keys[i]);});
}
```

Now executing this leave `keys[i]` in the callback, what I obviously do not want. I need to be able to loop through the keys array and pass the current value to the function call within the callback. How can I fix/ achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish this by using an outer function accepting the parameter.

```
for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    !function outer(i){
        document.getElementById("btn_"+i).addEventListener('click', function(){changeTab(i);})
    }(keys[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The event is also passed to the event handler. You can get the target element from there, like so:

```
addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  changeTab( event.target );
});`
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the callback in a separate scope to retain the value of `i`, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771767/4449942)

Comment: I tried to avoid using the target as it would require a regex to parse the actual string I need. Used an outer function to get through this. Thank you still